# The biggest square on a sphere

Tags: spherical-geometry

I wonder whether [**presented in wikipedia square**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square#/media/File:Square_on_sphere.svg) (with angles $120^{\circ}$) is the biggest (taking into account lengths of sides) possible square on a sphere?

- If not what is the biggest?
- If so how it can be proved?

*One can assume here definition of a square on a sphere:

**Square on a sphere** = the 4-sided polygon with equal length sides and equal angles, sides are determined by 4 different great circles.*

Comment: @Mathematician42  Is it not clear from the link ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square#Non-Euclidean_geometry for details..

Comment: Ah, only saw the picture, let's read it :)

Comment: Fix a point to be the north pole of your sphere. If one takes four equally spaced meridians, so that adjacent meridians are separated by $90^{\circ}$, then the four intersections of the meridians with any parallel (i.e., line of latitude) will define a square, and one can show that every square arises this way. One can see that as the chosen parallel approaches the equator, the side lengths monotonically approach one-quarter the circumference of the sphere. So, if you allow the degenerate square with four $180^{\circ}$ angles, that is the solution. If you do not, there is no maximum.

Comment: On the other hand, the square with $120^{\circ}$ angles is the largest one that can be used to tile the sphere uniformly, assuming again that one ignores the degenerate tiling by two hemispherical 'squares', which is a consequence of the fact that there is a tiling where three squares meet at each corner (just the central projection of a cube onto a sphere).

Comment: @Widawensen I second Mathematician 42's original suggestion to include the definition you use here, for self-containedness (and for independence of any future edits to the wiki).

Comment: @Travis Square on a sphere = the 4-sided polygon with equal length sides and equal angles, sides are determined by different geodesics. Travis, Is it sufficient definition ?